# Missing Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, path, filenames

I noticed that `GetInvalidFileNameChars()` method is missing in `Silverlight`. What is the best way to validate file names in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of regex,

```
string pattern = "[\\~#%&*{}/:<>?|\"-]";
string replacement = " ";

Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);
string final = Regex.Replace(regEx.Replace(input, replacement), @"\s+", " ");
```

Comment: No tool for that?:S I have to manually copy invalid characters from C#?

Comment: use this regex and check with the file name!

Comment: There are third party tool which you can check here http://wiki.sensenet.com/index.php?title=Business_Solution:_Integrating_a_SilverLight_multi-file_uploader_control